# Radio button groups in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code to attempt to select only one dish per category

```
@{ int i = 0; }
@foreach (var category in categories)
{
    <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">@category.Name</p>
    foreach (var dish in category.Dishes)
    {
        <input name="dishes[@i]" type="radio" value="@dish.Id" /> @dish.Name<br />
    }
    <hr />

    i++;
}
```

The problem is that using this code, when I check 2 radiobuttons, only one of them is getting saved, dishes shows up as an array with only the second item I checked

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Image")] Menu menu, int[] dishes)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      _context.Add(menu);

      IEnumerable<MenuDish> menuDishes = dishes.Select(id => new MenuDish { MenuId = menu.Id, DishId = id });

      _context.AddRange(menuDishes);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are having a problem.  I've copied your code and run it with some test data and it all works fine.

Comment: It seems the problem was that some categories didn't have dishes

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to select multiple options you should use checkboxes not radios.

Comment: I am using radios because I want to have one option per category but there are multiple categories with options

Comment: I see. Have you checked the array int[] dishes? Does it contain right values?

Comment: When I check 2 radio's, only the second value is added, assume I have dish id 0 and 1 (both in a different category), in the array I only see int[1]